# What are some sources to download previous Oracle Software versions? For example Oracle WebLogic Server 10.3.2

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic11g

Have searched extensively for free versions of archived software. Some links resulted in software downloads from not so trusted sites.

Comment: Oracle does not usually give away enterprise software for free. The reason you can't find a download from a trusted site is probably because there isn't one. (At least, not one visible to those members of the general public who have not given Oracle a lot of money.)

Comment: Have made modifications to the description to reflect free software version download intent. The same free software which was once made available by Oracle on OTN.

Comment: If you can't find it here https://www.oracle.com/downloads/index.html, it probably is not officially supposed to be downloaded according to Oracle's likely terms & conditions. BTW, StackOverflow is for questions specific to programming.

Comment: Previously when I needed Oracle 10g - which is currently not available on oracle.com/downloads/index.html, I was able to find on certain file-sharing sites/blogs viz., gokhan.ozar.net/oracle10g-xe/ . I could have posted this on Oracle forums but would likely not receive anything directly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download most of it from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

You need an account to download, but the accounts are free to create. (Not 100% sure on what level of access that gets you though).

Older versions are there, but can be hard to find - you just need to hunt...

Comment: I guess creating an account would give basic access unless there is corporate/paid account. And, yes finding certain legacy versions is hard.

Comment: There's definitely corporate accounts, but I'm pretty sure the free ones give you access to most software (and older versions going back to I think 10ish).

Answer (score 1):

there is link to download older versions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html
unfortunately oldest version is 10.3.6 )-: